# Is there a way to only alert when an engulfing candle is bigger than the previous 2 candles?

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v4

[2bearish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3cSE.png)
[2bullish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQrP0.png)

Basically im trying to work out how to signal that an engulfing candle engulfs the previous 2 candles of the opposite type...

eg. 2 bearish candles, then a bullish engulfing candle to is bigger than both bearish candles.

I have pieced together code from a few different engulfing candle scripts but have no idea what i'm doing.

obviously the code works to a point, but it is not showing all engulfing candles, but also the engulfing candles are only of the previous 1 candle.

Can somebody help please?

```
 [//bullish engulfing
twoBear = close\[1\] < open\[1\] and close\[2\] < open\[2\] 
bullEng = close > open and close > max(open\[1\], close\[2\])
buySig = twoBear and bullEng

twoBull = open\[1\] < close\[1\] and open\[2\] < close\[2\] 
bearEng = open > close and open > max(close\[2\], open\[1\])
sellSig = twoBull and bearEng


// Plot the 'triangle'
plotshape(buySig, title="Buy", location=location.belowbar, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, text="Buy", size=size.auto, color=color.blue)
plotshape(sellSig, title="Sell", location=location.abovebar, transp=0, style=shape.triangledown, text="Sell", size=size.auto, color=color.red)


alertcondition(bullEng, title = "Buy", message =     "\[CurrencyPair\] \[TimeFrame\], Bullish candle engulfing previous 2 candles")
alertcondition(bearEng, title = "Sell", message =     "\[CurrencyPair\] \[TimeFrame\], Bearish candle engulfing previous 2 candles")][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

ok iv got it working completely differently in case anybody else was trying to get the same thing working

```
 study("Engulfing", overlay=true)

//identify engulfing candles
//bullish closes higher and lower than previous 2 candles open and close
bullishEng = close >= open [1] and close > high [2] and open <= close [2] and close [1] <= open [1] and close [2] <= open [2]
bearishEng = close <= open [1] and close < low [2] and open >= close [1] and close [1] >= open [1] and close [2] >= open [2]
tradeSignal = (bullishEng) or (bearishEng)

//plot signals to chart
plotshape (tradeSignal and bearishEng, title="Sell", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0, style=shape.triangledown, text="Sell")
plotshape (tradeSignal and bullishEng, title="Buy", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, text="Buy")

//send out alert if candle meets our conditions
alertcondition(bullishEng, title="Buy", message="Engulfing Candle for {{ticker}}, wait for FVG to be taken to enter")
alertcondition(bearishEng, title="Sell", message="Engulfing Candle for {{ticker}}, wait for FVG to be taken to enter")
```